# CouchDB Returning None for Row Key (reduce function)

Tags: python, mapreduce, couchdb, map-function, couchdb-python

I have a map function and reduce function to count all the occurrences of a key. The code is below for CouchDB 2.0 design document:

**Map Function**

```
function(doc) { emit(doc.domainID, 1); }
```

**Reduce Function**

```
_sum
```

Here is a snapshot of what the browser shows:

[image: Map and reduce functions result]

And here is the result when I run the following code in Python:

```
import couchdb
couch = couchdb.Server("http://localhost:5984/")    
counts = couch['event_db'].view('doc/eventbydomainid',
                                 reduce=True, descending=True)
```

**Terminal result when printing key and value**

[image: Terminal result showing no key]

I am expecting the following result, but not seeing it:

```
{"ad1": 32, "ad2": 1}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a reduce function, the default behavior is to reduce the entire dataset to a single value. If you want grouping, add `group=true` to your request. ([documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=group))

And while you didn't ask about this specifically, you'll no doubt come across it while working with map/reduce in CouchDB. If you are emitting complex keys (eg: arrays), you can use the `group_level` parameter to group by the various parts of the array from left to right. ([example](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/ddocs/views/intro.html?highlight=group%20level#the-view-to-get-comments-for-posts))

An interesting use-case here is emitting a date as an array, such as: `[2017, 8, 29, 22, 59, 16]`. Using `group_level=1` will group by year, `group_level=2` will group by year+month, and so on. (pro tip: using `group_level` will set `group=true` implicitly)

Comment: Thank you so much Dominic! This is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Can you also recommend how I can get the count based on a starting or ending document ID? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you can do that via the `startkey_docid` and `endkey_docid` params. ([documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/views.html#db-design-design-doc-view-view-name))

Comment: Okay great. I will give it a try!